# fgets(STDIN) automatic line break?

Tags: php, text-files, stdin, fopen, fwrite

I noticed something with fgets(STDIN) in php

I have this code :

```
if($fd = fopen($filename, "a")){

    $message = fgets(STDIN);
    $message = $message.":";
    echo $message;
    //fwrite($fd, $message);
    fclose($fd);
}
```

I try for exemple to insert at the end of my text-file :

```
helloWorld
```

But i always have :

```
helloWorld
:
```

not :

```
helloWorld:
```

Is stdin makes a automatic line feed ? How to remove this automatic jump ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [stream_get_line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php) instead of fgets:

```
if($fd = fopen($filename, "a")){
    $message = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1024);
    $message = $message.":";
    echo $message;
    //fwrite($fd, $message);
    fclose($fd);
}
```

Or you can use [rtrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function to remove line endings:

```
if($fd = fopen($filename, "a")){

    $message = fgets(STDIN);
    $message = rtrim($message, "\n\r") . ":";
    echo $message;
    //fwrite($fd, $message);
    fclose($fd);
}
```